# Symbol lookup error while running FANN based program

Tags: c, linker, fann

I compiled a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <floatfann.h>
#include <fann.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    struct fann *ann = fann_create_standard(3, 28 * 28, 49, 10);

    fann_train_on_file(ann, "train.fann", 200, 10, 0.0001);
    fann_save(ann, "trained-1-0.7-3-784-49-10.net");
    fann_destroy(ann);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error at RUNTIME:

symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libfann.so.2: undefined symbol: log

The compilation command is:

```
gcc -lm -lfann train_acc.c -o train_ann
```

I already read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089336/fann-library-error-in-ubuntu-usr-local-lib-libfann-so-2-undefined-symbol-pow) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574996/how-to-add-fann-library-in-qt-creator-in-linux). I already tried to install, uninstall, remove, update every possible combination of libraries. I tried to download and rebuild the sources from FANN website, I tried to switch from x64 to x86. Still I get the same error.
I am running Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the linking order?

```
gcc train_acc.c -o train_ann -lm -lfann
```